# Play framework 1.2.4 using header footer template

Tags: pdf, footer, playframework-1.x

How is header footer template used to render PDF in play framework?

I was trying the below code -

options.header_template = "/header.html".

No matter what path I give for the html it always gives me file not found error. Could you please suggest where possibly could I be mistaking?

Comment: Is header.html inside the <project>/public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be options.header_template = "ControllerNamedFolder/header.html".
Where the ControllerNamedFolder is under app/views.
Thanks anyway...